# Is there any alternatives to parseFloat? Which enables me to process numbers up to 21 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

In my application, I need to handle some currency fields which deals upto 21 number of digits. And the values needed to be calculated for further actions.

I have used parseFloat in the calculations previously when the maximum digit is < 15. Now since the requirement is 21 digits, the parseFloat is not supporting properly. It supports up to 17 digits properly. But after 17th digits, it rounds off the value.

[image: Tried in Console window]

So is there any alternatives to parseFloat? or any other methods through which I can handle this issue?

Application Background:

- C# Application
- AngularJS, Javascript involved
- Database: SQL

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 1):

No, JS can only handle numbers of 16 integers, up to a maximum of `9,007,199,254,740,991` (aka [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)). It's a limitation of the language.

You can store them as strings if you simply need to display the values, but as soon as you perform a numerical operation on them JS will convert them to a Number type with the highest precision it can.

If you need a higher precision, then I would suggest you perform the calculation on the server and return the result as a string to your JS code.